# Trying to keep five set of image(png format) in continous animation

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to keep  five set of image(png format) in continuous animation  which should occupy full screen and after clicking on that popup  it should disappear.
There is same image with different position its feel like it is moving up and down continously. In the below code I have used only one image "good_job.png" as popup .But how to use five different image to show in motion up and down.Any help would be appreciated.

Xaml

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="contentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
    <Canvas RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True">
                    <Popup x:Name ="ppup" IsOpen = "False" IsLightDismissEnabled   = "True"
                           Width="420"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           >
                        <Image Source = "Assets/good_job.png" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Width="420"  />
                    </Popup>
                    <Popup x:Name ="ppup1" IsOpen = "False" IsLightDismissEnabled = "True"  
                           Width="320"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source = "Assets/wrong_ans.png" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Width="420" />
                    </Popup>
                </Canvas>
</RelativePanel>
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_0_0.png" Height="150" Width="160" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" Margin="30,40,0,0" Tapped="image1Tap" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, LeftMargin,                           RightMargin" />
```

C# Code

```
if ((image1.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource == new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_0_0.png", UriKind.Absolute) && (objNameWritten1.Text == "Banana")) 
{
    ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
    ppup.IsOpen = true;
    mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Audio/wow good job.mp3");
    mediaElement1.AutoPlay = true;

}
```

Comment: How about a `Timer` to update the `ImageSource` on a interval?

Comment: That is also acceptable but how to do achieve it.can you tell.

Comment: `var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);  timer.Elapsed += () => image.ItemsSource = NextImage(); timer.Start();`

Comment: @EpicSam can give example with above refrence it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This answers is untested and quickly thrown together. I submitted it because I was asked in the comments.**

First create a way to loop through the images.

```
private int CurrentImageId = 0;
private List<string> Images = new List<string>() { "image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5" };

private string NextImage() {
    CurrentImageId = (CurrentImageId + 1) % 5;
    return Images[CurrentImageId];
}
```

Then use a timer to reasign the `ImageSource` at an interval.

```
var timer = new Timer(100);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => Images.ImageSource = NextImage();
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Instead of a hardcoded 5, you could uses Images.Count.